# Issue with dynamic compiling of angular directive in IE7 and IE8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to dynamically compile a directive inside my application. What I tried is like;

```
    $scope.newPaneString = '<vmf-split-container>' +
        '<vmf-split-pane-component paneheight="30%" minwidth="30%" maxwidth="70%">' +
            <!--Some content comes in here-->
        '</vmf-split-pane-component>' +
        '<vmf-split-pane-divider paneheight="10px" clicks="0" close="bottom"></vmf-split-pane-divider>' +
        '<vmf-split-pane-component>' +
            <!--Some content comes in here-->
        '</vmf-split-pane-component>' +
        '</vmf-split-container>';
         $compile($scope.newPaneString)($scope)
```

Here `<vmf-split-container>` is the parent directive and `<vmf-split-pane-component>, <vmf-split-pane-divider>` are the child directives which depends on the parent directive using the require option of the directive like;

```
require: '^vmfSplitContainer',
```

Here is the issue. When I try to dynamically compile this directive using `$compile` I am getting the following error;

```
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$compile/ctreq?0=vmfSplitContainer&p1=vmfSplitPaneComponent
```

It's only happening with IE7 and IE8. Please help me out on this.

Comment: I think angularjs do not supported in ie7 or earlier version. Even for the IE8 needs to do some tricks. And in the later version it won't be supported even in IE8 also

Comment: I am using angular version 1.2. It will support IE7 and 8.

Comment: Please refer this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie and http://ng-learn.org/2013/12/Dealing-with-IE-family/ if you haven't. I think it will be helpful

Comment: try to use attribute notation instead element notation for IE to work.

Comment: @MadasuK Thanks a lot buddy..saved a lot of time for me. Attribute stuff solved the issue. :)

Comment: By the way I added to answer section, please accept it helps to be noted on answer key search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use attribute notation instead element notation for IE to work.